# How to block LDAP user account in spring security without locking the LDAP user?

Tags: java, ldap, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security. In my application authentication is done through `Ldap`.After Ldap authentication I want to handle failure and success events on login. I want to track login count in database for locking functionality.
any body knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is done by LDAP but you want to lock the ldap user after he logged in.

If you use spring 2.5 you can make your custom implementation of a [InitializingBean](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring/2.5.6/spring-2.5.6-sources.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.java?format=ok) and check if principal is a LDAP user:

```
public abstract class EventListener implements InitializingBean {

Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

EventDispatcher eventDispatcher;

// Spring will call this method after auto-
// wiring is complete.
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    // let us register this instance with
    // event dispatcher
    eventDispatcher.registerListener(this);
}

/**
 * Implementation of this method checks whether the given event can be
 * handled in this class. This method will be called by the event
 * dispatcher.
 * 
 * @param event
 *            the event to handle
 * @return true if the implementing subclass can handle the event
 */
public abstract boolean canHandle(Object event);

/**
 * This method is executed by the event dispatcher with the event object.
 * 
 * @param event
 *            the event to handle
 */
public abstract void handle(Object event);

public void setEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher eventDispatcher) {
    this.eventDispatcher = eventDispatcher;
}
}
```

And next implement this custom handle on your loginFailureEventListener (map this listener in your xml)

```
        public class LoginSuccessEventlistener extends EventListener {  

    @Override  
    public boolean canHandle(Object event) {  
        return event instanceof AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent;
    }  

    @Override  
    public void handle(Object event) {
AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent loginFailureEvent = (AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent) event;
        Object name = loginFailureEvent.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if(principal instanceof org.springframework.security.userdetails.ldap.LdapUserDetailsImpl){
            out.("LDAPUser: " + user.getUsername() + " failed login");
//do you thing here
        }
    }    
}
```

binding in XML:

```
<b:bean id="loginFailureEventListener" class="com.foo.bar.support.event.LoginFailureEventListener">
    <b:property name="eventDispatcher" ref="eventDispatcher"/>
</b:bean>
```

**EDIT:**
You can extend `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` and override the `onUnsuccessfulAuthentication` method:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends AuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private LoginDao loginDao;

    @Override
    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException {
        super.onSuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);    
        request.getSession().setAttribute("wrong", -1); 
    }

    protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        super.onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, authException);
        String username = (String) authException.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if(username.length() > 0){
            Login login = loginDao.read(username);
            if(login != null){
                request.getSession().setAttribute("wrong", login.getFailedLoginAttempts());
                request.getSession().setAttribute("attempts", Login.MAX_FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS);
            }else{
                request.getSession().setAttribute("wrong", 100);
            }
        }else{
            request.getSession().setAttribute("wrong", -1);
        }
    }

    public void setLoginDao(LoginDao loginDao) {
        this.loginDao = loginDao;
    }
}
```

Binning in XML:

```
<!-- Custom AuthenticationProcessingFilter with Callbacks -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManagerAlias"/>
<b:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" name="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.foo.bat.support.event.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter"> 
    <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManagerAlias"/>
    <b:property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/login.do"/>
    <b:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <b:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.html"/>
    <!-- loginDao is a HibernateDao that reads logins an write wrong attempts to DB -->
    <b:property name="loginDao"><b:ref bean="loginDao"/></b:property>
    <custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER" />          
</b:bean>
```

Now you can put this filter in your filterChainProxy

Look here for inspiration
http://www.harinair.com/2010/02/spring-acegi-security-account-lockout/

Comment: @Michel:Thanks for suggestion. I want to track  Login attempts  with the use of a loginCounter in database. Incrementing the counter once a user tries to authenticate. Reset the counter to 0 after the user successfully authenticates. so after `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentials` Event how can I redirect page to login page with Locked account message?

Comment: @amit31 I think you need to look to a custom `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` and overide the function `onUnsuccessfulAuthentication` here do you have a `request` object where you can put some attributes in `(request.getSession().setAttribute("locked",true)`. In a simple JSP you can read this attributes and show some messages. Please let me know if you need an example...

Comment: @Michel: sorry for late reply. I'm new to all this things . could you please provide example so that i can understand it in better way.

Comment: @amit31 Add an example to my answer

Comment: @Michel: I dont want to locked ldap user. i want to locked user using database. In our application authentication is done through ldap. After ldap it retrive userdetails data from table. so afer ldap authentication is fail or success i m checking lockingcounter in database. if logincounter > 5 then i want display message as locked user account on login page. so where should i add 'AuthenticationProcessingFilter' in my code?

Comment: How can i redirect my class on a specific page when i got the event AuthenticationSuccessEvent? I've implemented counting the invalid login on the page and saving it to the db. Now i want to redirect to a specific page after N failed login attempts.?

Comment: @amit31 You don't have to do this because your custom AuthenticationProcessingFilter is in the filterChainProxy. So your springconfiguration is handeling this. otherwise you can use the `request.getSession().setAttribute("wrong", true)` and read this attribute from your `login.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

What locking functionality? Are you aware of the LDAP Password Policy extension, that manages all kinds of stuff like this for you? e.g. lockout after several unsuccessful logins, password expiry/lock/mandatory reset, password quality polices, ...

Comment: @EJP , thanks for suggestion, basically i want to locked account using database. i dont want to locked account through ldap.M y approch is Login attempts can be tracked with the use of a counter in database. Increment  the counter once a user tries to authenticate. Reset the counter to 0 after the user successfully authenticates. so initailly check user and password with ldap. after authentication(fail or success) is done through ldap i want set counter in database and after five fail item locked user account. so after ldap authentication is done how can i handle locking funality?

Comment: @amit31 why do it all yourself? LDAP will do exactly all of that , without you having to write a line of code.

Comment: @EJP I think he don't want to lock the whole LDAP user but only for his application. is that possibly with LDAP(through blocking certain requests?) or is this done with blocking certain roles(groups) for a LDAP user?

Comment: @michel there's no evidence for that conjecture, and it would be poor security practice.

Comment: @michel: @ EJB :  Is it possible to add some filter before ldap authentication ?. so initially it goes to filter and checks whether loginitems is greater than 5 or not. if login items is greater than 5 then it does not go into ldap authentication and if login items is less than 5 then it goes into Ldap authentication.

Comment: @amit31 LDAP authentication does that all in one go. I don't see where splitting it up gets you. It wouldn't be atomic for a start.

Comment: @michel: @EJB: thanks for your suggestion.  i have replace  `ldapAuthenticationProvider` by 'CustomAuthenticationProvider' which extends `LdapAuthenticationProvider`. In this override public Authentication `authenticate method` and check login items in database for current user. if login items is greater than five then throw Locked Exception else  return `super.authenticate(authentication)`. this is working fine. Thanks a lot for your support.....:)